# about syntax in javascript using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am struggling with javascript syntax... I did not found concrete information on the internet.

Here the simplified structure of the code :

```
/******/(function (modules)
{ // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/function __webpack_require__(moduleId)
{
    /******/
    /******/        // Check if module is in cache
    /******/if (installedModules[moduleId])
    {
        /******/return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
        /******/
    }
    /******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
    /******/var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
        /******/i: moduleId,
        /******/l: false,
        /******/exports: {}
        /******/
    };
    /******/
    /******/        // Execute the module function
    /******/modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
    /******/
    /******/        // Flag the module as loaded
    /******/module.l = true;
    /******/
    /******/        // Return the exports of the module
    /******/return module.exports;
    /******/
}
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/__webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/__webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/__webpack_require__.d = function (exports, name, getter)
{
    /******/if (!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name))
    {
        /******/Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
            /******/configurable: false,
            /******/enumerable: true,
            /******/get: getter
            /******/
        });
        /******/
    }
    /******/
};
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/__webpack_require__.n = function (module)
{
    /******/var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
    /******/function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
    /******/function getModuleExports() { return module; };
    /******/__webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
    /******/return getter;
    /******/
};
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/__webpack_require__.o = function (object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/__webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 11);
/******/
})
([
/* 0 */
(function (module, exports, __webpack_require__)
{//some declaration
}),
(function (module,exports, __webpack_require__)
{//some declaration
}),
//etc...
})
]);
```

As far as I understand, this is a definitions of a list of modules which are treated through webpack. My syntax problem append at the end of "function(modules)" which terminates with a ")" and directly (without any ",") comes the first module. So, it syntaxly leads to something like that :

```
(function (param){
    //some declaration
})
//???? 
([   
(function (param1,param2,...){}),
(function (param1,param2,...){})
]);
```

What is the meaning of the syntax next to the "//????" comment ?

Comment: It's an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

Comment: Thank you !! I did not realized it ! You help me so much understanding (I am serious x_x).